# renderWith not overriding the Template

Tags: php, silverstripe-4

I have create a controller to override a template if it finds a parameter with value but for some reason it is not overriding the default template.

```
<?php

namespace {

    use SilverStripe\CMS\Controllers\ContentController;
    use SilverStripe\Control\Controller;

    class ForSalePageController extends ContentController
    {
        /**
         * An array of actions that can be accessed via a request. Each array element should be an action name, and the
         * permissions or conditions required to allow the user to access it.
         *
         * <code>
         * [
         *     'action', // anyone can access this action
         *     'action' => true, // same as above
         *     'action' => 'ADMIN', // you must have ADMIN permissions to access this action
         *     'action' => '->checkAction' // you can only access this action if $this->checkAction() returns true
         * ];
         * </code>
         *
         * @var array
         */


        protected function init()
        {
            parent::init();

            $printVar = Controller::curr()->getRequest()->getVar('print');

            if ($printVar && $printVar === 'portrait') {
                $this->renderWith('PrintPortrait');
            }

        }

    }
}
```

even though there is a parameter that match the value it still rendering the page with the default template `ForSalePage.ss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init()` method is not for returning data or setting the template. That's the  `index()` method (or action) good for. The index action is the default action and it has to return something. Either a rendered string or an array with data to render with in the default template.

You want to overwrite the default template and return the rendered string, so this should work:

```
    public function index()
    {
        

        if ($printVar && $printVar === 'portrait') {
            return $this->renderWith('PrintPortrait');
        }

        return []; //default

    }
```

[See docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/controllers/introduction/#introduction-to-controllers)